# Port manipulation

Tags: arduino-uno, code-optimization, port-mapping

My UNO having some stability issues because of  heavy memory use, I'm now optimizing the code
now looking to reduce the digital read memory use with the help of port manipulation. I got the code for      'digitial write' but no idea for the digital read pinMode(powerStatus, INPUT);digitalRead(powerStatus)
Thanks

Comment: how can direct port manipulation instead of digitalWrite/Read reduce dynamic memory use?

Comment: Did you read [the Arduino tutorial on the subject](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation)?

Comment: for optimizing my code

Comment: @EdgarBonet yes

Comment: So you have already read the answer to your question. If you tell us what specific part of that tutorial you found confusing (maybe add a quote), we could try to help clearing up the confusion.

Comment: less code will free flash, but not SRAM. even 100% use of flash will not create stability issues

Comment: "Heavy memory use" as you put it does NOT cause "stability issues".  What EXACTLY do you mean by "stability issues" here?  If you mean that the part doesn't run reliably and resets itself, it's more likely you have a power supply issue.  If would really help if you would edit your question and indicate exactly what you are doing, what problem you are seeing, etc.  General terms like "stability" and "heavy use" really mean nothing.

Comment: Stop using `String` in your code. That will cure 99% of all memory stability issues.

Answer (score 2):

To read a pin you simply read the port the pin is part of then mask out which pin within that port you want to read.

For example to read pin D11 you need to read bit 3 of port B.

```
if (PINB & (1 << 3)) { 
    // HIGH
} else {
    // LOW
}
```

However this doesn't address the underlying problems you're having with your sketch.  Saving on flash memory by optimizing your code will not fix instabilities (if anything it will introduce new instabilities from new untested code).

Instabilities related to memory are due to a lack of (or fragmentation of) SRAM not flash.  Optimizing code like this will save flash, but won't directly affect your SRAM usage at all.

Instead you need to optimize your SRAM usage by:

- Make sure all string literals are kept in PROGMEM by using the `F()` macro where appropriate
- Avoid use of `String` and instead stick to `char *` with pre-allocated buffers.
- Don't use `new` and `delete` or `malloc` and `free` as this will fragment your heap and cause instability (this is the underlying problem with `String`).